# How to erase all records from a database when using LINQ and tableadapter?

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql, tableadapter

I am trying to load data from Excel file to DataGridView in my Form. First I load all data from excel sheet into dataset then put all that data in database using C# LINQ and then I just set the DataGridView.DataSource to name.BindingSource and that is it. I get all the data in DataGridView but when I try to load the data again (I have closed my program and changed some cells in Excel) the new data is just appendend to the previous data but I want only the new data...

So my question is: How to delete all records in database or in LINQ or TableAdapter just to delete RECORDS.... :) getting frustrated by this.

I am trying to clear a database dataset by using nameDBDataset.table.Clear() but nothing, trying to use TableAdapter to delete but again nothing.

help please...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, its really quite simple... duh :)

nameDataContext dc = new nameDataContext(); 
dc.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE name-of-the-table");

Thats it...